# Java Android Virtual Joystick

Tags: java, android, joystick

I tried creating my own custom joystick for my android game and i encountered some problems while i tried to smooth the joystick animation.I made a sphere and created a bounding circle for it ,then placed the joystick inside the sphere (made a bounding circle for the joystick too) . So whenever the joystick bounding circle would intersect with the sphere's bouding circle the joystick would stop.I managed to stop the joystick but it stays stuck.I want it to be able to move the joystick inside the sphere (any direction) even if i'm not touching inside the sphere,how do i manage that?

P.S : TouchEvent = MotionEvent

Here's my best code so far

public class Controller {

```
public float ControllerPosX;
public float ControllerPosY;
public float ArrowPosX, ArrowPosY;
public float CurrentPosX, CurrentPosY;
public double Angle;
public BoundingCircle ControllerCircle, ArrowCircle;
public boolean ControllerLocked, ArrowLocked;

public Controller() {

}

public void Update(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents) {
    int len = touchEvents.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        TouchEvent event = (TouchEvent) touchEvents.get(i);
        if (event.type != TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {
            if (!ControllerLocked) {
                ControllerPosX = event.x;
                ControllerPosY = event.y;
                ControllerCircle = new BoundingCircle(Assets.Sphere,
                        ControllerPosX, ControllerPosY);
                ControllerLocked = true;
            }
            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DRAGGED) {
                Angle = GetAngle();
                ArrowCircle = new BoundingCircle(Assets.Joystick, event.x,
                        event.y);

                if (BoundingCircle.Intersect(ControllerCircle, ArrowCircle))
                    ArrowLocked = false;
                else
                {
                    ArrowLocked = true;
                }

                if (!ArrowLocked) {
                    ArrowPosX = event.x;
                    ArrowPosY = event.y;
                }
            }
        } else {
            ControllerLocked = false;
        }
    }
}

public double GetAngle() {
    return Math.atan2((double)ArrowPosX, (double)ArrowPosY) *180/Math.PI;
}
```

}
'

Comment: Do you mean that when you take your finger off, you want the joystick to return to the centre?

Comment: No,let's say i go with my joystick TOP of my screen,if i move my finger to the left i want it (the joystick) to move left (in that boundary) but it's not and i tried everything to make it work,any idea/suggestion?